# incompatibility with libssl-dev on Ubuntu 18.04, I need libssl1.0-dev on my build path

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor, buildpack, libssl

But I can't see to be able to install it with an `apt-get install libssl1.0-dev` command.

I get these errors for a dependency of one of my dependencies :

```
remote: [12/14] Compiling Crypto Cipher+Method.swift
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher+Method.swift:144:35: error: use of undeclared type 'EVP_CIPHER'
remote:     public var evp: UnsafePointer<EVP_CIPHER> {
remote:                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher.swift:71:34: error: use of undeclared type 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX'
remote:             UnsafeMutablePointer<EVP_CIPHER_CTX>,
remote:                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher.swift:72:27: error: use of undeclared type 'EVP_CIPHER'
remote:             UnsafePointer<EVP_CIPHER>,
remote:                           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher.swift:77:34: error: use of undeclared type 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX'
remote:             UnsafeMutablePointer<EVP_CIPHER_CTX>,
remote:                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher.swift:84:34: error: use of undeclared type 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX'
remote:             UnsafeMutablePointer<EVP_CIPHER_CTX>,
remote:                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher.swift:89:19: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX'
remote:         var ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX()
remote:                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher.swift:135:13: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup'
remote:             EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx)
remote:             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/HMAC/HMAC+Method.swift:23:28: error: use of undeclared type 'EVP_MD'
remote:     var evp: UnsafePointer<EVP_MD> {
remote:                            ^~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/HMAC/HMAC.swift:25:23: error: use of unresolved identifier 'HMAC_CTX'
remote:         var context = HMAC_CTX()
remote:                       ^~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/HMAC/HMAC.swift:26:9: error: use of unresolved identifier 'HMAC_CTX_init'
remote:         HMAC_CTX_init(&context)
remote:         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: /tmp/build_d568f3fb9152fe1c7ee4ab9b68dc80fe/.build/checkouts/crypto/Sources/Crypto/Random/PseudoRandom.swift:9:15: warning: 'RAND_pseudo_bytes' is deprecated
remote:         guard RAND_pseudo_bytes(&random, Int32(count)) == 1 else {
remote:               ^
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Hello Ronan, thank you. I thought I would be able to compile my project when the `libssl1.0-dev` was installed, and I couldn't do it with the `apt install` command in the `pre-compile` file. Heroku support explained to me how to do it thanks to the `heroku-buildpack-apt` and the `Aptfile`.

But my project using **Azoy/Sword** Discord Library still won't compile on Heroku's Ubuntu 18.04, more specifically the **CTLS** target used by the `vapor/engine` dependency.

Comment: I discussed with the Library developer and he's going to make use of something else in a coming update.

Comment: I leave the link to [`heroku-buildpack-apt`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) in case somebody else wants to install something, a library, deb or repository, it's possible thanks to the Aptfile.